# How to stop Veracrypt if wrong password entered

Tags: veracrypt

Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Using Veracrypt 1.25.9 for an encrypted partition.

This is a minor inconvenience but would be nice to know what to do:

I open Veracrypt (from GUI) and try to mount my encrypted partition, entering the password when prompted. If I mistype (without realising), it then tries to decrypt - and spends a long time doing so before letting me know (the standard window pops up saying 'This process may take a long time and VeraCrypt may seem unresponsive').

If I typed correctly it mounts the partition in 3 seconds; if I mistype it takes 55 seconds to tell me ('Operation failed due to one of the following...').

My question is - say 5 seconds after it starts trying to decrypt it'll be obvious I've mistyped; is there a safe / quick way to stop it continuing or is it best just to be patient (and obviously just type more carefully in the first place!)?

Just to be clear, I know the password and it's all fine if I type correctly, just in my haste every now and then it wastes a bit of time.

Many thanks.

Comment: Such long delay is a security feature, not a bug so, not fixable.

Comment: Ah I see - to prevent multiple attempts in a short space of time - makes sense, thank you. I’ll type more carefully!

Comment: Yes, that's it. Ubuntu and most distros have also some delay, deliberately programmed, whenever we type the wrong password.